# Does a persistent tracker cookie become a session cookie if I setMaxAge(-1)

Tags: java, servlets, session-cookies, httpcookie

I am creating a servlet to capture cookies. I want to make all the cookies active only for that session. 
I have setMaxAge(-1)
Just need to confirm if this will kill the cookie after the session?

Comment: You should be able to check the documentation for this answer...http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html#setMaxAge(long)

Comment: Thanks gpojd. Pasting that part of the document for someone else's reference.

Comment: setMaxAge

public void setMaxAge(long expiry)
Sets the maximum age of the cookie in seconds.
A positive value indicates that the cookie will expire after that many seconds have passed. Note that the value is the maximum age when the cookie will expire, not the cookie's current age.

A negative value means that the cookie is not stored persistently and will be deleted when the Web browser exits. A zero value causes the cookie to be deleted.

Comment: @Santhoshkp please post that comment as an answer and then mark it as the answer.  That way people who have the same question will be able to find the answer easier.

Answer (score 0):

setMaxAge public void setMaxAge(long expiry) Sets the maximum age of the cookie in seconds. 
A positive value indicates that the cookie will expire after that many seconds have passed. Note that the value is the maximum age when the cookie will expire, not the cookie's current age.
 A negative value means that the cookie is not stored persistently and will be deleted when the Web browser exits. A zero value causes the cookie to be deleted.

Thank you all for your assistance.